# How to automate publishing of a babelified package in travis

Tags: npm, babeljs, travis-ci

I'm trying to automate the release process of an npm package ([GitHub link](https://github.com/itslanguage/itslanguage-js)) using Travis.

The package is built using babel. The output directory should be published. This process can be scripted fairly easy:

```
npm run babelify
cd build
npm publish
```

However, from my understanding, an [`npm`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/) provider should be used, because this sets the `api_key` and `email` parameters in `.npmrc`. This removes the ability to change the current working directory.

The relevant deploy section of `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
provider: npm
email: kvdb@d-centralize.nl
api_key:
  secure: KlsdLI5KOLYV...
on:
  tags: true
skip_cleanup: true
```

How can I publish a babel build to `npm` using Travis?

Answer (score 0):

Think you already managed to publish it?

`% npm search itslanguage
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
itslanguage               | The core JavaScript… | =kvdb…          | 2016-12-06 | 0.3.11   |`

This is the result of the most recent build from a tagged commit.

Answer (score 0):

@joepd

Another dev here on that project.

Travis did not publish the build folder to the npm. That deployment and the 11 previous ones are basically the entire project folder which we do not want.